# How to use the update API from highcharts in angular2-highcharts

Tags: angular, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to implement synchronized charts using angular2-highcharts. I also have a dynamic Y axis. So my chart `options` for the `yAxis` change based on the user input. 
In highcharts there is an way to [update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) the option and render the chart again. Is there a way to do the same using Angular2-highcharts.

Comment: This might help you: http://embed.plnkr.co/pnkc8Iw9cSrCYn9zr0VZ/

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for examples in synchronized charts, where I have different Y axis